# Google Maps v 3.2 - Satellite View turns white

Tags: api, maps, satellite

I have written code that displays a map perfectly on a basic HTML page. However, when I embed it in my existing website code, all the functions work with the exception of "Labels" in Satellite view. When the Labels box (submenu of Satellite view) is clicked all imagery disappears from the Satellite view and the background turns white.

I suspect that one or more of my CSS classes is interfering with the Labels code but I don't know which one. If I knew how the Google API Satellite layer is coded perhaps I could figure it out. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is a link to the map: http://landcallnow.com/man105_map.html